# What are the differences between curve NIST P-521 and Edwards E-521 for signature?

Tags: elliptic-curves, dsa, nist

I implemented and used the P-521 curve for ECDSA. Signatures are 132 bytes long.
It seems that Edwards E-521 is safer but I did not investigated very deeper.

What is its signature length ?

How is it better ?

Comment: Library recommendations are off topic, so I'm editing that part out.

Comment: Do you want to compare ECDSA using P-521 with ECDSA using E-521 ?

Answer (score 3):

> What is its signature length ?

Depends on what algorithms you use, but with ECDSA the signature length is twice the length of the order of the base point. For P-521 that's 1042 bits, or 132 bytes when using whole bytes for each part. For E-521 it's 1038 bits or 130 bytes.

> How is it better ?

The design criteria for E-521 are stated in [A note on high-security general-purpose elliptic curves](http://eprint.iacr.org/2013/647):

> The curves Curve25519 and Curve1174 have been engineered to facilitate simple, efficient and secure implementation of general-purpose elliptic curve cryptosystems, with impressive results [8]. On these grounds, it makes sense to look for similar curves at higher security levels.